# Pass-by-reference and integral promotion

Tags: c++, type-conversion, pass-by-reference, overloading, integer-promotion

Why isn't the compiler able to promote `char` to `int&` but has no problem when passing it by reference-to-const (`char` to `int const&`)?

Example code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void func1(int & i)       { cout << "int &       " << i << endl; }
void func2(int const & i) { cout << "const int & " << i << endl; }

int main() {

    char mychar = 'a';
    func1(mychar);    // compiler-error
    func2(mychar);    // no error

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is allowed:

```
char c = 'X';
const int& i = c;
```

We're implicitly promoting `c` to `int` and binding `i` to that temporary. This can't really lead to any confusing behavior. `i` has the same value `c` did, it's just a different type.

But what would happen if the same logic were allowed with *non*-`const`:

```
char c = 'X';
int& i = c;
i = 'J';
```

`i` can't bind directly to `c` - it's the wrong type. We'd still need to promote `c` to and `int` and bind `i` to that temporary. But when we assign `i`, we're just modifying that temporary we bound - `c` would still be `X`. That would be incredibly confusing, non-intuitive, and error-prone. So the language forbids it.

Answer (score 2):

Promotions and conversions create a new temporary object. Non-const references cannot bind to temporaries.